# Splitting a string keeping the delimiters in the result - C#

Tags: c#

I would like to split a string with delimiters but keep the delimiters in the result.

How would I do this in C#?
I searched trougth several post, but none helped me with the answer.

Example

```
string stringToSplit = "(10)12345(20)dk34jf(3)li33";
```

Result I need is

```
(10)12345  
(20)dk34jf  
(3)li33
```

Comment: Split the string by `(`, remove empty strings and then add the `(` back to each of the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using regular expressions to split the string based on the delimiters and then include the delimiters in the resulting array. Here's an example:

```
string stringToSplit = "(10)12345(20)dk34jf(3)li33";
string pattern = @"\(\d+\)\w+";
var matches = Regex.Matches(stringToSplit, pattern);

foreach (var match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}

// Output:
// (10)12345
// (20)dk34jf
// (3)li33
```

Snippet in JS:

```js
let stringToSplit = "(10)12345(20)dk34jf(3)li33";
let result = stringToSplit.match(/\(\d+\)\w+/g);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Did you [try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/geTsT5)? The output is different

Comment: I didn't try this one indeed, but changed it now to what I had before.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach without regex is splitting by `(`:

```
string stringToSplit = "(10)12345(20)dk34jf(3)li33";
string[] result = stringToSplit.Split('(', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => "(" + s)
    .ToArray();
foreach (string match in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

---

```
(10)12345
(20)dk34jf
(3)li33
```

Answer (score 1):

[This approach](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rkpTaP) works also if the number inside the brackets is not at the beginning of the string:

```
string stringToSplit = "(10)12345(20)dk34jf(3)li33";
//string stringToSplit = "12345(20)dk34jf(3)li33";

var res = stringToSplit.Split("(")
        .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
        .Select(i => {
            return i.Contains(")")? "(" + i : i;
    }).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', res));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regular Expression like this:

```cs
string stringToSplit = "(10)12345(20)dk34jf(3)li33";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(\d+\)[^\(\)]+");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(stringToSplit);

foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}

/*
Output:
(10)12345
(20)dk34jf
(3)li33
*/
```